# Context menu on nested ListView in Xamarin

Tags: c#, listview, xamarin, contextmenu

I am working on a Xamarin application, which has a nested ListView with a Context Menu on every item within this nested ListView.
When one clicks on a item in the sub ListView, which belongs to an item in the top ListView, the item in the top ListView is triggered but not the sub-item, which was clicked.

I created an example, which can be found on [Github](https://github.com/hobber89/XamarinNestedListViewContextMenuExample)

I tried to bind BindingContext as parameter for the Action but it gave me the top level item, so I did not commit this change.

Can please anyone tell me how to fix it or give me the link to a working example.

Kind regards,
theDult

Comment: please read [ask] before posting.  The relevant code needs to be included in the body of the post, properly formatted, not in an external repo.

Comment: Hi Jason,
I did not post any code in the body of the post because it is quite much relevant code (MainView with a ViewModel, which creates the item hirachie, which is shown in ContentView on which a ViewModel is bound and can contain another instance of itself if there are sub items). I just wanted to give the possibility to look at my code, if the problem is not understood.

But I would be very happy if you can write me how to fix it or post a link to a working example.

Kind regards, theDult